# installing airflow on mac virtualenv gives: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: pip, python-wheel, pep517

In virtual environment I'm trying to install apache-airflow.
macOS: 10.13.6
Python: 3.9

```
(airflow_venv) $ sudo -H pip install  apache-airflow==1.10.12  --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.12/constraints-3.7.txt
```

after installing quite some other wheels, for pandas I get the following error -

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I've tried updating wheel and pip.

Answer (score 1):

change to python3.8, python3.9 has some compatibility issues